# Python web-srabing Проблемы с заполнением AJAX формы

Tags: python, ajax, selenium-webdriver, data-mining

Делаю парсер, требуется заполнить AJAX форму

```
    ECode = driver.find_element_by_class_name("input")
    ECode.click()
    ECode.send_keys(used_code)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.67)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему. Кому интересно:

```
    ECode = driver.find_element_by_class_name("input")
    actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(ECode)
    actions.click()
    actions.send_keys(used_code)
    actions.perform()
```